# Android - ListView onItemClick has no effect

Tags: android

Im creating an Android app and trying to add a click listener to a listview. The class implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener and the method onItemClick has no effect. Im using a simpleadapter.

Relevant Code.

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SummaryListView);
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);


@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Adapter Code

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.summary_list_item,cursor,from, to, 0);
//
        list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: If the list contains some items that take focus like Button, you have to set focusable = false in all these items.

Comment: Beautiful. 6 x Textviews in the item layout. Works now. Thanks. Any ideas how i would get a value from the list? for example a textview.getText() of one of the textviews so i can send through an intent.

Comment: Read it from the adapter e.g. getItem(position) which will return your model object. then select whatever you want from it.

Comment: Not quite sure what to do next. Something like dataAdapter.getItem(position); How do i actually get the value from a textView on the item called idText ?

Comment: can you post the code of how do you fill the adapter with data? what is the type of data filled ?